# I need to navigate the buttons in the modal using arrow keys left and right

Tags: angular, typescript

Am using angular and this is the button code i need to navigate it using left and right arrow now the navigation through buttons is working with tab but not with arrow keys.

```html
<div class="modal-footer>
    <button type="submit" tabindex="o" class="btn btn-primary tab" (keydown)=movecell($event)(click)="onAcceptOffer()">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" tabindex="1" class="btn btn-secondary tab" (keydown)=movecell($event) (click)="modal.dismiss('Crossclick');
            isClicked=false">Cancel</button>       
</div>
```

```js
    //.ts file
length: 0;
domEles;
movecell(e) {
    const activeEle = document.activeElement;
    const activeEleIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.domEles,     activeEle);
    if(e.key == "ArrowRight" && activeEleIndex < this.length - 1 ) {
        activeEle.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
        
    if(e.key == "ArrowLeft" && activeEleIndex > 0) {
        activeEle.previousElementSibling.focus();
    }
}
        
ngOnInit() {
    this.domEles = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-footer> *');
    this.length = this.domEles.length;
}
```

Comment: This is the normal behavior. Tab key is used for navigation and this convention is important in term of accessibility. If you really need arrow keys to change your focus, you should try using ElementRef from Angular to access each button.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to implement it

Comment: Yes, but there are still unclear things in your question. How do you focus the button in the first place ? Is there no focus at all and as soon as key ArrowRight is pressed the focus is on the right button ? Or do you focus one button with Tab then you use arrow keys to switch between both of them ?

Comment: does the focus works with the event function which is implemented there?

Comment: can you share a code snippet regarding your logic? it would be a great help.